# log4net is not working on process exit

Tags: c#, log4net

How can I log message with log4net on application exit event?

In example I use only console appender for logging:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message%newline"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

In application I want to write final message on `ProcessExit` event.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("test");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            log.Info("Application started");

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnApplicationExit);

            log.Info("Application is going to exit");
        }

        static void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnApplicationExit called");
            log.Info("Application exit");
            Console.WriteLine("OnApplicationExit exit");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Application started
Application is going to exit
OnApplicationExit called
OnApplicationExit exit
```

Seems that appender was closed before `OnApplicationExit` call.

Is it possible somehow log any messages on application exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnApplicationExit);
```

before instanciating log4net logger

```
class Program
{
    private static  log4net.ILog log = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnApplicationExit);
        log= log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("test");
        log.Info("Application started");



        log.Info("Application is going to exit");
    }

    static void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("OnApplicationExit called");
        log.Info("Application exit");
        Console.WriteLine("OnApplicationExit exit");
    }
}
```

results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works, result is not very readable, but anyway works.

Comment: @Serbin results is just the title of the console app output screenshot I've posted at the end of my post